# curl testing with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, heroku

```
Cannot GET /search-result/ac
```

i get this error when i do he curl testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzEGf.png)

how do i resolve this as this is all my code

```
   const resultHTML = `
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
             <!-- Block2 -->
             <div class="block2">
                 <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew" id="itemLabel">
                     <img alt="IMG-PRODUCT" id="itemImage">
                 </div>

                 <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
                     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5" onclick="getItemDetails(event)">
                        <span id="itemId" hidden></span><span id="itemTitle"></span>
                     </a>

                     <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
                         $<span id="itemPrice"></span>
                     </span>
                 </div>  
             </div>
         </div>
    `;
    function getItemDetails(event) {
      const itemId = $(event.target)
        .siblings('span')
        .text();
      window.location.href = '/product-detail?itemid=' + itemId;
    }

    function getSearchResult(value){
      if( value !== ""){
        $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/search-result' ,
          data: {
            value: value
          },
          success: res => {
            if (res.success == 0) handle_error(res.error);
            else {
              res.data.rows.forEach(row => {
                const $itemList = $(resultHTML);
                $itemList.find('#itemImage').attr('src', row.picture);
                $itemList.find('#itemId').text(row.item_id);
                $itemList.find('#itemTitle').text(row.title);
                $itemList.find('#itemPrice').text(row.price);
                if (row.sale == true) {
                  $itemList
                    .find('#itemLabel')
                    .removeClass('block2-labelnew')
                    .addClass('block2-labelsale');
                }
                $('#searchresult').append($itemList);
                window.sessionStorage.clear();
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      const searchValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('searchValue') || ''; 
      getSearchResult(searchValue);

      $('#btnSearch').on('click',function(){
        const value = $('.search-product input').val();
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('searchValue', value);
        window.location.href='/searchresult';
      })
    });
 and the server.js file 

app.get('/search-result', async (req, res) => {

  const client = await pool.connect();
  let value = req.query.value;
  value = striptags(value.replace(/'/g, "\\'")).trim();
 // console.log('final value: ' + value);
  const query = `SELECT item_id, title, price, picture, sale FROM items 
   where title ilike '%${value}%' ORDER BY item_id; `;
  await client.query(query, (err, result) => {
    if (err)
      res.json({
        success: 0,
        error: err
      });
    else{
      res.json({
        success: 1,
        data: result
      });

    }
  });
  client.release();
});
```

is there anyone out there that would help me to get the results from the curl testing. is it because i cache the search result and afterwards deleted imediately

Comment: `/ac` isn't a query string element it's part of the path. Try updating your route to `/search-result/:term` they access it by using `req.params.term`

Comment: also look here for more info regarding routing: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html